# Protractor test: Is it able to block/freeze the DOM during test execution?

Tags: javascript, testing, dom, browser, protractor

I'm executing the Protractor test in angular web application.

## Test Case:

1. Find elements in the list.
2. Loop through every element in the list.
3. If an element contains the required name.
4. Click at the element.

## Code:

```js
let projectsList = await element.all(by.css(Selectors.projectList));
for (item of projectsList) {
    item.getText().then((text) => {
        if (text.includes("50_projects_to_tests")) {
            console.log(text)
            item.clik()
            
        }

    }, (err) => console.log(err));
}
```

## Problem:

The test case is straightforward to execute except one thing.
Request about updating information in the project is sending every few second.
When the response back from the server I'm loosing the selected list of projects before.

It means that I'm not able to click at the element which I found because the element no longer exists.

I receiving:

`StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

## Question:

**Is it possible to block/freeze the DOM while the test is executing?**

Any ideas would be appreciable to handle the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Getting stale element references while looping is a common problem

First note is that you should try avoid using `.then()` for managing promises if you already are using `async/await`, it just makes things more difficult to read.

Secondly I would caution against disabling the refresh if that's not how the applicaiton works when a enduser will be interacting with it.

The following answer is based on the assumption that after the page refreshes the same elements will be found by `element.all(by.css(Selectors.projectList));`. In this answer the whole element array is recaptured during each loop but it stores the index value of the element it needs so the loop proceeds

```
let projectsList = await element.all(by.css(Selectors.projectList));

for(let loopCount = 0; loopCount < projectsList.length; loopCount++){
    projectsList = await element.all(by.css(Selectors.projectList));

    const item = projectsList[loopCount];
    const itemText = await item.getText();

    if (itemText.includes("50_projects_to_tests")) {
        console.log(itemText )
        item.clik()
    }
}
```